How to combine confidence interval (or standard error, or standard deviation) for the sum of 2 fitted parameters
I am fitting a linear mixed model with the equation:
$$
y = \beta_0 + X_1 * \beta_1 + \text{random effects} + \epsilon
$$
I use the model to compare difference of means between two groups, $X_1$ is a dummy variable encoding of group where $x_{1i}$ $=$ $1$ if the measurement is taken in group 1.
With that said, I believe in my model:
$\beta_0$ = Mean of group 2
$\beta_1$ = difference between mean of group 1 and mean of group2
$\beta_0$ + $\beta_1$ = mean of group1
I wanted to be use the model outcome to plot, specifically use the confidence interval as error bars. While I can easily get the confidence interval for $\beta_0$ (mean of group 2) and $\beta_1$ (group difference) from the fitted model (sadly in matlab not in R, but I think the fit function are similar enough). I wasn't sure how can I construct the confidence interval for the sum of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ (which I believe is the mean of group 1).
The output of the fixed effect section looks something like this:
Fixed effects coefficients (95% CIs):
    Name                   Estimate     SE           tStat     DF      pValue        Lower        Upper   
    {'(Intercept)'}        0.0xxxxx     0.0xxxxx    5.8245    1837    6.7493e-09     0.060224     0.12137
    {'group'   }           0.00xxxxx    0.00xxxxx    3.392    1837    0.00070864    0.0025449    0.009522

I have very little background in statistic. All the knowledge I have now is from a combination of online sources, so they could be wrong. If you leave an answer, can you try to explain that in a little bit more details and background. Apologies if this a redundant question, and if that is the case please point me the right direction.
Thanks a lot!

"$\beta_0+\beta_1$" is called a contrast.  Its standard error is computed in exactly the same way as the standard errors of coefficient estimates: namely, using the variance-covariance matrix of all the coefficient estimates.  If you don't want to do that calculation yourself, simply re-run the model with a different parameterization or variable coding so that $\beta_0+\beta_1$ is directly estimated and automatically output.

@whuber Thank you for the answer. Just a follow up question on the parameterization solution. If I wanted standard errors of all three. Do I add a $\beta_2$ that encodes for group1, while keeping everything else the same. Will that then mean $\beta_0$ will encode for the difference between $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ ? Or does that mean I run an opposite model where $x_{1i}$ = 1 if the measurement is from group2, and thus make $\beta_1$ the mean of group1. Then use the opposite model in parallel so I can I all three standard error?

It's the latter, because standard software will not automatically output all the contrasts you might wish to examine.  You also need to be aware that these estimates tend to be correlated, sometimes strongly so.

@whuber Sorry can you elaborate a little on your last sentence? What estimates are you referring to and why are they correlated?

Look under the "Estimate" column in your example!  They are almost always correlated unless $\beta_0=0,$ as you can see by graphing the data (ignore the random effects) and imagine wiggling the fitted line: changes in the slope cause the intercept to change.

@whuber Oh I understand now. Thank you very much!
